# General questions about php and react.js

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, backend

I'm about to learn react.js but I have a lot of questions,

1. if I'm learning react do I need PHP?
2. Do I need PHP with react.js and how will I use it inside PHP if possible
3. if I do PHP do I need React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React.js is a javascript front-end library. It is fully written in javascript and that is the only language you need to know to use it.

PHP is a scripting language that is generally used to create the backend of your applications.

So yes you could technically develop your backend using PHP and then use React to create the frontend of your application, however it would be easier to simply use javascript to create both the backend and the frontend of your project.

If you're interested in backend development using javascript, I recommend you start by looking at node.js and the express.js library.

Comment: So react.js not recommended for php instead using pure js with php, really sorry for taking too much of your time.

Comment: I want react to not refreshing the page every time I change the values in the backend

Comment: No problem. As I said earlier, you can definitely build your backend using PHP. You would have to create an API that would allow you to fetch data from a database for example. Once you create different api endpoints, you can connect your frontend to your backend easily.

Comment: React doesn't refresh if you update the datastore in your backend. The way it works is that you can store data your app's "state" and then display that data. When the state changes, the app "refreshes". But if you simply change the data in the backend without actually fetching it once again (by making API calls), the app won't refresh.

Comment: I would advise to learn about all the different technologies available and understand how they work. Once you understand what each technology can do and it's limitations, it becomes easy to choose which ones you want to use to build your project.